# Update column in table if column in other table matches value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update the following table

```
CREATE TABLE public.drawings
(
  drawing_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('drawings_drawing_id_seq'::regclass),
  drawing_number text,
  discipline text,
  type text,
  ownership text,
  required_asbuilt boolean DEFAULT false,
  service_type text,
  design_requirement text,
  current_asbuilt_approved boolean,
  CONSTRAINT drawings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (drawing_id)
)
```

Setting `required_asbuilt=false`. I want to set that false when the `drawing_id` column matches `drawing_id` column in `revisions` and if `eb_suitability_status='obsolete'` appears in one of the rows of `revision`.

```
CREATE TABLE public.revisions
(
  revision_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('revisions_revision_id_seq'::regclass),
  drawing_id integer,
  basis_revision text,
  filename text,
  sequence integer,
  title text,
  rev_1 text,
  revision_date date,
  suitability text,
  design_status text,
  revision_note text,
  eb_url text,
  eb_suitability_status text,
  eb_review_acceptance_status text,
  CONSTRAINT revisions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (revision_id),
  CONSTRAINT revisions_drawing_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (drawing_id)
      REFERENCES public.drawings (drawing_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

What's the best way to achieve this? Using postgresql 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply want an `update`?

```
update drawings d
    set required_asbuilt = false
    where exists (select 1
                  from revisions r
                  where r.drawing_id = d.drawing_id and
                        r.eb_suitability_status = 'obsolete'
                 );
```

If you actually want to set it to `true` is all other cases (that is, update *all* the rows), then you can put the `exists` in the `set`:

```
update drawings d
    set required_asbuilt = exists (select 1
                                   from revisions r
                                   where r.drawing_id = d.drawing_id and
                                         r.eb_suitability_status = 'obsolete'
                                  );
```